# Is Stack Exchange a PHP application?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies were used to build the Trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy)

just interested.

Comment: It's .NET application

Answer (score 2):

See here:

> **[What was StackOverflow built with](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)**

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was .NET, SQL Server, and .NET MVC.